# MySQL - Using results from one query in another query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query that gives me back rows with two columns each containing an id.

```
SELECT idEng, idDutch
FROM phraseConnections
WHERE cat = '3'
```

the id's are from other tables where they are connected to a phrase i want to get.

I tried something like this.

```
SELECT a.phrase, b.phrase
FROM phraseEnglish as a, phraseDutch as b
WHERE a.id = (SELECT idEng
FROM phraseConnections
WHERE cat = '3')
and b.id = (SELECT idDutch
FROM phraseConnections
WHERE cat = '3')
```

thanks.

Comment: what error its showing??

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` if you use the result for a comparison. In general, however, I would prefer a join.

Comment: @user3091574 It its not showing an error but it doesn't give the right result back, it needs to give the phrase's where the id's are connected in the table phraseConnections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use Joins:

```
SELECT
   a.phrase,
   b.phrase
FROM
   phraseConnections pc
INNER JOIN
   phraseEnglish AS a
ON
   pc.idEng = a.id
INNER JOIN
   phraseDutch AS b
ON
   pc.idDutch = b.id
WHERE
   pc.cat = 3;
```

If you want records that have no corresponding row in one (or both) language too then you could use outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

The error must be because of inner query returns more than one value.

Try using `IN`:

```
SELECT a.phrase, b.phrase
FROM phraseEnglish as a, phraseDutch as b
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT idEng
           FROM phraseConnections
           WHERE cat = '3')
and b.id IN (SELECT idDutch
          FROM phraseConnections
          WHERE cat = '3')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is probably because You can't ask to have a single value equal a set of multiple values.
To correct this in your SQL, use `In`.

```
SELECT a.phrase, b.phrase
FROM phraseEnglish as a, phraseDutch as b
WHERE a.id In 
        (SELECT idEng
         FROM phraseConnections
         WHERE cat = '3')
    and b.id In
        (SELECT idDutch
         FROM phraseConnections
         WHERE cat = '3')
```

However, this query can be done without subqueries:

```
SELECT e.phrase, d.phrase
FROM phraseConnections c
   join  phraseEnglish e 
     on e.id = c.idEng
   join  phraseDutch d 
     on d.id = c.idDutch
Where e.Cat = '3'
```