# Request on result of a request in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, request

The title says all,
I have a request like "Select [...]" and I want to do another request on the result of the first one. I didn't find anything relevant about that anywhere, and I found a solution where I create a temporary table where I put the result of my first request, then I request this table to get my final result, and I drop the table, but I absolutely want to avoid this super-heavy way. Any idea ?

Comment: subqueries, joins, there are plenty of possibilities.

Comment: Please add an example, best with a working [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) of the tables and the desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581451/mysql-using-results-from-one-query-in-another-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with : `WITH` instruction .

more doc here : http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/91893.aspx

Comment: You can't do it with `WITH` in MySQL of today.

Comment: As VMai said, I had searched for WITH but found out it's not working in MySQL anymore.
Thanks to both of you for helping me, I finally got the answer just by some reflexion (I'm really such a noob sometimes) but as my example is very specific, I can't post the asnwer without explaining all my work and it would take too much time and place. 
Hint : I used a subquery like you suggested me and it seems to perfectly work. Thanks again ~